# Why am I having a problem with intellij and maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

**Environment:**

```
macOS Monterey
Java: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
Intelij IDEA: 2022.3 Build #IU-223.7571.182, built on November 29, 2022 
Intelij bundled version of maven: 3.8.1
Command line Maven: Apache Maven 3.8.6
```

My question has two part:

**1) How does intelij's internal build system work with maven to identify dependencies that are needed for compiling code?**

**2) When that dependency resolution fails, how you can you determine the cause of the failure?**

**The problem:**

I have a multi module maven project.

From the maven window in Intelij, I can build any module and the whole project. From the command line I can run maven builds that complete with out error. However when I try to build project, or rebuild project from the Intelij menu. (Build->Build Project) the build fails.

It fails with the following error:

> java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist.

The pom file includes the dependency for the jar file. I can go to each directory and execute this command

```bash
mvn dependency:tree | grep -i jackson-annotations
```

and I get:

> [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.8:compile

In each pom file the following dependency exists:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) attached. It may help if you delete `.idea` directory and [reimport the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start).  `idea.log` may contain the related exceptions or you can see them in the Build | Sync tool window if the dependency resolution fails.

Comment: I believe that is pretty common misbehaviour in IntelliJ, I primarily face with it when switching between branches, sometimes "Reload All Maven Projects" circle might help, sometimes restarting IntelliJ helps, last time I was need to remove IntelliJ caches in `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains`